# Limit the number of rows in a table in JSP print page

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

I have created a list with result set values in which each column element is separated with `::` and more than 50 rows using the java code given below.(`arr1` is the array list and `temp` is a `String`)

```
int j=0;
while(resultSet11.next()){
   temp=((++j)+"::"+resultSet11.getString("productname")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("exp")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("batch")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("qty")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("foc")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("mrp")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("rate")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("amount")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("taxper")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("taxamount")+"::"+resultSet11.getString("nettaxamount")+"::") ;
                            
   arr1.add(temp);
   rowcount++;
            
   bean.setFirstarray(1);
                        
}
request.setAttribute("nextpagedetails", arr1);
```

Then I iterated this array list to get these values in a HTML table using the below code.

```
<table>
<s:iterator var="stat" value='#request.nextpagedetails' >
 <tr>   
   <s:iterator status="arr" value="#stat.split('::')" var="des">       
   <td>
     <s:property value="#des"/>
   </td>
  </s:iterator>
 </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

But the problem is this iteration wont stop untill the values in the list ends.
Since I am using this table in a print page, there is more than one page. So the second page is coming only after filling the entire portion of of the first page.
Is there any way to limit the number of rows in a page using this method.

[image]

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you really want because the printer must detect that the HTML `<table>` needs to be split in several pages. Maybe you want to use `<s:if>` to detect how many rows have been already written as HTML and then want to create a new table.

Comment: What database are you using for returning the result set?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code using index property of status variable.

```jsp
<table>
<s:iterator var="stat" value='#request.nextpagedetails' >
 <tr>   
   <s:iterator status="arr" value="#stat.split('::')" var="des">
       <s:if test="#arr.index <=50">       
            <td>
                <s:property value="#des"/>
            </td>
        </s:if>
  </s:iterator>
 </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to know how many rows you need to render on the view. You can use a parameter in the URL to pass to the action that sublist/subarray values before you return them to the view.

Splitting array/list on multiple pages called a pagination. If you need to learn more about this feature you might read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876945/573032) answer.